# Is it possible to use reuse django form in django rest framework serializer for validation?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-rest-framework

Is it possible to reuse existing forms written as django forms in django rest framework serializers validation?

I would like to keep the logic of the forms and don't spend a lot of time for doing rewrites.

If it's possible - what's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

It has been 4 years since you have asked and most probably you have better answer for this, however I investigated and the outcome was:

- yes it is possible to serialize form but not ModelForm, check:

https://django-rest-framework-braces.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html#

- as much as I like the idea, there's no easy way built-in DRF to do so, simply it was not designed for this.

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#custom-renderers

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/html-and-forms/#rendering-forms